# Read Google Play settings, specifically "Auto-add widgets" setting, for creating a shortcut

Tags: android, google-play-services, shortcut, google-play

I'm trying to conclude the best approach for creating a shortcut for my app, but avoid creating it if Google Play automatically created one for me. Whether Google Play automatically creates a shortcut after download is based on the following user setting (which has a deceiving name, by the way):

[image: Google Play app settings]

Is it possible to read this Google Play app setting from within my app? If I need extra permissions, that's okay. Or, at least, do you know since what exact Android version is this setting enabled by default?

Comment: Since this is one of the first google hits on my search, and I cannot find a better place to ask. This setting is *not* about adding a widget, but a shortcut / launcher icon on the homescreen, is it?

Comment: You are right, this is for creating a shortcut in the homescreen. Not sure if it also has other effects related to widgets, though.

Comment: Did you found a solution on this already?